# Can you hold two working visas for two separate countries at once?

Tags: visa, germany

I do not believe this is a duplicate, but if it is please just point me in the correct direction.

I currently hold a three year working visa for Germany and have recently received an offer to run some Christmas markets in London. Can I hold working visas in both Germany and the UK at once? I hold an American passport.

Furthermore, does anyone know if I need to already hold a work visa in the UK to receive a liqueur handlers permit?

Comment: Flagged for migration to Expats.

Comment: The question in the last paragraph ought to be asked separately.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is no reason this should be a problem, you can certainly hold multiple visas from different countries at the same time, even work and/or long-stay visas.

However, depending on local law, obtaining a residence permit elsewhere and leaving the country for an extended period of time might have other consequences like making your work permit more difficult to renew, delaying eligibility for naturalisation/permanent residence or even allowing the authorities to rescind it.

All this because the foreign work permit can be interpreted as evidence that you do not intend to make your first country of residence the centre of your life anymore, which is often a requirement for some of these things (again, depending on local law, there is no general rule).

Under the same logic, working for a few weeks in the UK should have no consequences.